# Correct drawing when tiling a CGPattern

Tags: ios, core-graphics, quartz-core

I'm trying to fill a rect with a CGPattern, painting the typical bar with stripes. I obtain this.

[image]

The code of the pattern (not the entire bar) is this

```
CGContextSaveGState (context);

CGColorSpaceRef patternSpace = CGColorSpaceCreatePattern(NULL);
CGContextSetFillColorSpace(context, patternSpace);
CGColorSpaceRelease(patternSpace);
CGFloat alpha = 0.25f;
static const CGPatternCallbacks callbacks = {0, &DrawStripesPattern, NULL};
NSNumber *cellSide = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:kTAGBarHeight];
CGFloat cellSideFloat = [cellSide floatValue];

CGPatternRef pattern = CGPatternCreate((__bridge void *)(cellSide),
                                       CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, cellSideFloat, cellSideFloat),
                                       CGAffineTransformIdentity,
                                       cellSideFloat,
                                       cellSideFloat,
                                       kCGPatternTilingConstantSpacing,
                                       true,
                                       &callbacks);
CGContextAddPath(context, [path CGPath]);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextSetFillPattern(context, pattern, &alpha);
CGContextFillRect(context, barRect);
CGPatternRelease(pattern);

CGContextRestoreGState (context);
```

The pattern cell has the same side of the height of the bar (look at `kTAGBarHeight`) and the drawing callback is drawing 5 reegular oblique lines inside the cell rect. It looks good but if you zoom a little...

[image]

The lines are being clipped to the cell rect so it looks like that. I have two questions:

1. Why the pattern is not being drawn at origin (0,0) in the rect of
   the bar as I specify in `CGPatternCreate`? Could it be the absence
   of transform in the third parameter?
2. How I can avoid that annoying effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, solved :P

In my drawing callback instead of drawing 5 lines I draw 7, the first at point (0.0f, 0.0f) and the seventh at point (maxX, maxY). That joins the lines correctly.